# "Circular" Function Declaration in SML

Tags: function, sml, function-declaration

I want to use functions in a "circular" way, as shown in the following example:

```
fun cll1 (s)= cll2(s);
fun cll2 (s)= cll3(s);
fun cll3 (s)= cll(s);
```

Writing this produces an error in SML that the constructor `cll2` is unbound. Could someone help me write something along these lines? It's possible in C; I'd like to write it in SML.

Comment: It compiles in C, but that's because nearly everything compiles in C. What do you really want? You propably don't want to cause infinite recursion...

Comment: no i dint want an infinite recursion...its not the whole code i would give certain termination conditions ..i just wanted to know that how could i use a function before declaring it..the answer given below satisfies my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the `and` keyword.

```
fun cll1 s = cll2 s
and cll2 s = cll3 s
and cll3 s = cll s
```

Obviously these definitions won't do since it's an infinite recursion (ordinarily you'd test for a base case in one or more of the functions), but that's the general form.

Comment: well, they'll /compile/; they just don't halt. well, not very quickly, in any case.

Comment: @sreservoir: Ha, nice catch! What can I say? Halting is overrated.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, since `cll1` depends on `cll2`, `cll2` on `cll3`, and `cll3` on something unrelated (i.e. the functions aren't actually as circular as you think), you could just as well write

```
fun cll3 (s)= cll(s);
fun cll2 (s)= cll3(s);
fun cll1 (s)= cll2(s);
```

(of course, in this case, since it's all the same, one might as well write `val (cll1,cll2,cll3) = (cll,cll,cll)`. but that's probably not very pointful.)

that is, this has nothing to do with circular definitions, not as you've stated your problem; the same occurs with

```
val a = b
val b = 0
```

(if the intent is that a = b = 0).

the point to be made here is that, unlike functions in c, declarations in sml are evaluated in order and you have to be explicit if you want to refer to something you haven't declared yet -- and `and` is the usual way of doing so, yes, because, semantically, in any case, it indicates that the set of functions is intended to be taken together, so that they *can* refer to each other.